# How to make animated armature move in opposite direction

Tags: animation

I added a path curve which I extended as a straight line. Then I clicked on the armature in object mode and then shift-right clicked on the path. Then I hit control p and selected follow path (path constraint option didn't work). When I hit the play button the armature walks but it goes in the wrong direction. How do I make it go in the opposite direction?

[image: walk opposite direction]

As you can see to the bottom right I tried to add a constraint to -Y but the pink area shows that something is missing. The extraneous parts that you see around the armature shows that the import created a messed up rig. But the walk cycle works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You chose to both parent the armature to the curve with *Follow Path* AND to give it a *Follow Path* constraint. You should choose either one or the other solution.

**1) Follow Path constraint**: So, first solution, unparent the armature and keep the *Follow Path* constraint. In the *Follow Path* constraint, choose the curve as *Target*. Click on the *Animate Path* button. If you see that the armature goes in the bad direction, select the curve, go in *Edit* mode and click <kbd>W</kbd> > *Switch Direction*. If you want to control the speed of the animation and the position of the armature at any time, you need to remove the *Generator* that has been automatically generated when you pressed the *Animate Path* button: Select your curve, go in the *Graph Editor*, on the left panel unfold the *BezierCurve* track to select *Evaluation Time*, then display the *Graph Editor* properties panel with <kbd>N</kbd>, select the *Modifiers* tab, and remove the *Generator*. Now to control the speed and position of the armature keep your curve selected, go in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Path Animation*, and put some keyframes on the *Evaluation Time*.

**2) Parent with Follow Path option**: Second solution, instead of *Follow Path* constraint you could prefer to simply parent with *Follow Path* option, in that case, same thing, if you see that the armature goes in the bad direction, select the curve, go in Edit mode and click <kbd>W</kbd> > *Switch Direction*. Then delete the *Generator* and use the curve *Evaluation Time* to animate the armature.

[image]